# Can a google form contain a virus or other malware?

Tags: malware, google, google-apps

Just wondering if this is possible? A newsletter I'm applying to be featured in needs my information to be filled out on a google form. I remember Word documents used to be vulnerable to macro viruses, and I was wondering if anything similar is possible in a google doc/spreadsheet/form.

Comment: Can ______ contain a virus or other malware?  The answer to this question cannot be answered other than "yes" or "not yet".

Comment: Not that it is exactly what you asked, but Google docs have been used as C&C servers for malware.  https://blogs.forcepoint.com/security-labs/carbanak-group-uses-google-malware-command-and-control

Answer (score 2):

A Google form is a page hosted by Google to collect information from sources in text boxes, radio buttons etc. We cannot say that it is 100% secure but it is highly unlikely that you will get infected via a Google form unless it happens to include a link to a malware and you actively click on it.

As far as Google docs or spreadsheets go, again, it is unlikely since Google scans all documents on the cloud. In short, while theoretically it may be possible, practically, to my knowledge, there are no cases of macro viruses spreading through Google docs or spreadsheets or forms.

Comment: Awesome. I couldn't find much when I searched either. I opened it up in Firefox with NoScript and adblock on and it seemed benign, and I also ran it through VirusTotal. Thanks for the response!